# EF Core ignore property only to INSERT

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to setup my entity to retrieve data from 2 properties that doesn't exist on the table, basically by doing rawSql. When I mapped these 2 properties at entityBuilder, it just worked fine, but then when I tried to insert new data from this entity, I received an error related the missing columns at the table. When I set Ignore to these properties, it resolved the lack of column error, but stopped retrieving data. Is it possible to ignore columns/properties only to Insert/update direction? In this case, properties PlatformDescription and DriverDescription.

Thanks everyone!

```
        public OrderMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> entityBuilder)
        {
            entityBuilder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.CreationDate).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.ModifiedDate);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.CreatedBy).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.ModifiedBy);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.AutomobilePlate);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.DriverDriversLicense);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.LoginChecking);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.LoginPacking);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.LoginPicking);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.LoginDispatching);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.Platform);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.TrackingCode).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.PlatformDescription);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.DriverDescription);
            entityBuilder.Ignore("PlatformDescription");
            entityBuilder.Ignore("DriverDescription");
        }
```

```
var query = "SELECT A.Id ";
                query += ",A.AutomobilePlate ";
                query += ",A.CreatedBy ";
                query += ",A.CreationDate ";
                query += ",A.DriverDriversLicense ";
                query += ",A.LoginChecking ";
                query += ",A.LoginDispatching ";
                query += ",A.LoginPacking ";
                query += ",A.LoginPicking ";
                query += ",A.ModifiedBy ";
                query += ",A.ModifiedDate ";
                query += ",A.Platform ";
                query += ",A.Status ";
                query += ",A.TrackingCode ";
                query += ",B.Description PlatformDescription ";
                query += ",B.Complement ";
                query += ",C.Description DriverDescription ";
                query += " FROM [Order] A ";
                query += " LEFT JOIN Setup B ";
                query += "   ON A.Platform = B.Id ";
                query += " LEFT JOIN Setup C ";
                query += "   ON A.DriverDriversLicense = C.Id ";
                query += "WHERE A.CreationDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) ";

                return entities.FromSqlRaw(query).ToList();
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. Why are you trying to use raw sql? Did you want to  define this entity as having no table (`entityBuilder.ToView(null)`)? You also seem to have misunderstood the purpose of `Ignore`, it's for having an object property that is not backed by a database column.

Comment: `... retrieve data from 2 properties that doesn't exist on the table` - how can you retrieve data from something that does not exist on the table! What am I missing here?

Comment: @atiyar left join

Answer (score 0):

Given your sql query;

```sql
SELECT A.Id
,A.AutomobilePlate
,A.CreatedBy
,A.CreationDate
,A.DriverDriversLicense
,A.LoginChecking
,A.LoginDispatching
,A.LoginPacking
,A.LoginPicking
,A.ModifiedBy
,A.ModifiedDate
,A.Platform
,A.Status
,A.TrackingCode
,B.Description PlatformDescription
,B.Complement
,C.Description DriverDescription
 FROM [Order] A
 LEFT JOIN Setup B
   ON A.Platform = B.Id
 LEFT JOIN Setup C
   ON A.DriverDriversLicense = C.Id
WHERE A.CreationDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

It looks like you really just want to define 2 entities with their associated navigation properties. That way you don't need to use raw sql at all;

```cs
public class Order {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Platform { get; set; }
    public int? DriverDriversLicense { get; set; }
    // snip
    public virtual Setup SetupPlatform { get; set; }
    public virtual Setup SetupDriver { get; set; }
}

public class Setup {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }
    // snip
}

public OrderMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> entityBuilder)
{
// snip
entityBuilder
    .HasOne(e => e.SetupPlatform)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Order>(e => e.Platform);
entityBuilder
    .HasOne(e => e.SetupDriver)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Order>(e => e.DriverDriversLicense);
}
```

It is possible to force each `Setup` navigation property to be loaded whenever the `Order` is loaded;

```cs
.HasForeignKey ... 
.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetIsEagerLoaded(true);
```

And define extra properties, for convenience, that aren't mapped to the Order table in the database;

```cs
public class Order {
    [NotMapped]
    public string PlatformDescription => Platform?.Description;
    [NotMapped]
    public string DriverDescription => SetupDriver?.Description;
...
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Lakeman! It sounded promising, but when added EagerLoaded, I got an error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
with a null stacktrace

Comment: You got it mate, thanks! But regarding eager loading, I had to use Include to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

Just use [NotMapped] for your 2 new properties that don't exist in this table. For example, Order Model class,

```
public class Order
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string NewProperty1 { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string NewProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

### EDITED

[image]

[image]

You can use this linq and change these tables and columns to your own tables and columns.

```
var setup = db.TSetup;
var list = (from a in db.TOrder
            from platform in setup.Where(x => x.Id == a.Platform).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from driver in setup.Where(x => x.Id == a.DriverDriversLicense).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new TOrder()
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                PlatformDescription = platform.Description,
                DriverDescription = driver.Description
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't do. His properties correspond to columns that he wants to read from.

Comment: Did you use [NotMapped] before? Still can read from. [NotMapped] with column can be read when select and get ignored when insert/update.

Comment: I have used it. It means the properties are excluded from the EF model. They are not mapped to a database column

Comment: NotMapped didn't work:
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'"

Comment: @Tbocc, you need to remove entityBuilder.Property(o => o.PlatformDescription);
            entityBuilder.Property(o => o.DriverDescription);
            entityBuilder.Ignore("PlatformDescription");
            entityBuilder.Ignore("DriverDescription");

Comment: Hey @Asherguru! Well, if I remove both ignore and property mappings, it does make the entry work, but it doesn't retrieve data from these fields anymore. :(

Comment: It should work. I always use [NotMapped]. Are your new property names in Order model class same as your raw sql query? eg, public string PlatformDescription { get; set; } public string DriverDescription { get; set; }

Comment: oh, just checked. FromSqlRaw cannot work. Only linq can work.

Comment: Hmm, sounds good! I'll try to implement that way and let you know. tyvm!